# How to make edits to a deployed react app? (Netlify)

Tags: reactjs, build, netlify

if you have already deployed a build to Netlify by dragging your build files over & you want to make an edit to the site, do you just delete the build file in VScode, make the edit & create a new build file and drag that back into Netlify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login into netlify and go to the particular sites that you have previously deployed and in the deploys section just drag and drop the new build file